# Retrieve App role assignments using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I'd like to retrieve a list of users from an Azure AD App role by means of the Azure CLI.

I am able to fetch some of my application's metadata by issuing
`az ad app list --app-id <app-id>`. The resulting JSON does include the `appRole` for which I want to fetch all assigned users.

From the [`az ad app` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest) I only understand that App roles can be used in conjunction with `az ad app create` or `az ad app update`, but this is not what I am looking for.

I also tried `az ad group member list --group <group-id>` but this command apparently only applies to AAD groups, not to App roles.

How can I simply retrieve a list of users assigned to a certain App role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don’t have any CLI command to get the assignment list for an app role. Because the app role is something which belongs to tenant, and we don’t have tenant parameter for the command **az role assignment list**. Below is the official doc for your information.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest%23az-role-assignment-list)

We have only one way to fetch the assignment role list is through portal.
[image]

Comment: The question is about _app_ role assignments, but the screenshot shows role assignments of a normal built-in role. I can't find application roles in the depicted Azure portal page, so that screenshot seems misleading to me.